# What is mysql unprivileged username?

Tags: mysql

I have a question. what is mysql unprivileged username?
I am trying to install a cpanel software. But it wanted Mysql unprivileged username and password.

Comment: Usernames are created by the DBA, except for the initial "root" user that's privileged.

Answer (score 0):

The user doesn't have write(CREATE, UPDATE, ALTER, etc) permission maybe. When a new user is created, DBA have to specify the permissions to grant to them.

You may grant permissions using GRANT.
Read - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

eg: Create a user with custom permissions,

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON db2.invoice TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Here `jeffrey` will have ALL permissions on db1 and only select in db2.